# Issue I don't understand about jest mockImplementation

Tags: angular, jestjs

I'm new to testing and I'm sure there is something I don't do properly

I want to test an Angular Service :

UserService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { API } from '@app-commons/core/API';
import { AuthService } from '@app-commons/services/AuthService';
import { CameraService } from '@app-commons/services/CameraService';
import { MessageController } from '@app-commons/controllers/MessageController';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    public constructor(private api: API,
                       private auth: AuthService,
                       private cameraService: CameraService,
                       private message: MessageController) {}


    public async changePicture() {

        try {
            const imgData = await this.cameraService.selectPicture();
            const response = await this.api.put(`user/picture`, { picture: imgData });
        }
        catch (err) {
            this.message.warningToast("Erreur lors de l'envoie de votre image, vous pouvez réessayer.", 3000);
        }

        this.message.okAlert('Super !', 'Votre image sera visible dans quelques instants !');
    }
}
```

And here is my test

UserService.spec.ts

```
import { UserService } from './UserService';


const api: any = {
    get: jest.fn(),
    put: jest.fn()
};

const auth: any = {};

const cameraService: any = {
    selectPicture: jest.fn()
};


const messageController: any = {
    warningToast: jest.fn(),
    okAlert: jest.fn()
};


const userService = new UserService(api, auth, cameraService, messageController);

describe('UserService : changeImage', () => {

    test('should take a picture, upload it and display a message', async () => {
        cameraService.selectPicture.mockReturnValueOnce('base64Image');

        await userService.changePicture();
        expect(messageController.okAlert).toBeCalled();
    });

    test('should not make an api call if camera error', async () => {

        cameraService.selectPicture.mockImplementation(() => { throw new Error(); });

        await userService.changePicture();

        expect(api.put).not.toBeCalled();
    });

});
```

the first test pass but I have an error on the second one.

```
● UserService : changeImage › should not use api if camera error

    expect(jest.fn()).not.toBeCalled()

    Expected mock function not to be called but it was called with:
      ["user/picture", {"picture": "base64Image"}]

      69 |         await userService.changePicture();
      70 |
    > 71 |         expect(api.put).not.toBeCalled();
         |                             ^
      72 |         // expect(messageController.warningToast).toBeCalled();
      73 |     });
      74 |
```

We can clearly see, it's in the second test, but it called the method with the parameters defined in the first one: 'base64Image' and .... I totally don't understand why ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Mock Function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api) remembers all the calls made to it.

In this case `api.put` gets called *during the first test*.

Since it hasn't been cleared, it still reports that it was called when checked in the second test.

Use [`mockFn.mockClear()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear) to clear any previous calls to the mock function:

```js
test('should not make an api call if camera error', async () => {

    api.put.mockClear();  // clear the mock

    cameraService.selectPicture.mockImplementation(() => { throw new Error(); });

    await userService.changePicture();

    expect(api.put).not.toBeCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: @jeremycastelli awesome, glad to hear it was helpful!